# CSS background color is not showing up in div

Tags: css, html, colors, background

The background color for a 'sidebar' div is showing in my dreamweaver design but not when opened in a browser (chrome or IE),
Link to view the page: [Dropbox Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8740721/newstevesite/index.html).
It is the div under 'rehearsals' title, #sidebar in the css code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#848484">

<div class="wholepage">
<div class="tophalf">
<div class="logoimg"></div>
<div class="namelogo"></div>
<div class="pic1"></div></div>



<div class="bottomhalf">

<div id="sidemenu"><h4>R E H E A R S A L S</h4></div>
<div class="pic2"></div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
<li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
<li><a href="rehearsals.html">rehearsals</a></li>
<li><a href="recording.html">recording</a></li>
<li><a href="teaching.html">teaching</a></li>
<li><a href="equipment.html">equipment hire</a></li>
<li><a href="audio.html">audio specialists</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>

<div class="content"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

div.wholepage{
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
div.tophalf{
    width:900px;
    height:236px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
div.logoimg{
    float:left;
    width:255px;
    height:236px;
    background-image:url(images/tree.gif)
}
div.namelogo{
    float:right;
    width:645px;
    height:110px;
    background-image:url(images/logo.gif)
    }

div.pic1{
    float:right;
    width:645px;
    height:126px;
    background-image:url(images/pic1.jpg)
}

div.bottomhalf{
    width:900px;
    height:700px;
}

#sidemenu{
    float:left;
    width:163px;
    height:698px;
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:#black;
}

h4{

    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#white;

}
div.pic2{
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
    width:735px;
    height:125px;
    background-image:url(images/pic2.jpg);
}
#menu{
    float:right;
    width:733px;
    height:33px;
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid white;
}
#menu p { 
    color:#FFF; 
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    }

#menu ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:6px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-top:7px;
}
#menu li
{
display:inline;
}

#menu a:link,a:visited
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
padding:13px;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;

}
#menu a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#0099FF;
}


div.content{
    float:right;
    width:735px;
    height:540px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this property value in #sidemenu:

```
background-color: #black;
```

with this property value:

```
background-color: black;
```

I hope this will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the issue though `black` and `white` are not hexadecimal units though if you want to have hexadecimals here are the two hex codes you would need:

Black:

```
#000
```

or

```
#000000
```

White:

```
#fff
```

or

```
#ffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this and it will work fine. Hex code is required if you use #

```
<style>
#sidemenu {
    border: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
    height: 698px;
    width: 163px;
    background:#000000;
}
</style>
```